# Center multiway tree root in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in HTML / CSS and I would like to center the root between node **2** and **4**. I thought about a fixed distance between node **2**, **3** and **4** and then center the root in relation to the whole graphic.

If it's possible, I would like to turn the whole graphic to the left by 90°.

Any help is appreciated!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
}

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">2</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">2.1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">2.2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">3</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">3.1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">3.2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">4</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">4.1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to turn the whole graphic to the left by 90° I suggest using CSS transforms.
Since your block does not have a set width and height I would set it to `display: inline-block` to limit its width and being able to rotate it the way we want to.

To center the top element and/or to have a set width for each nodes, either use a min-width on the different element (I've given it the class `.special`) or give him node childs and set their opacity or visibility to 0 afterward. If you use the min-width solution, you'll need to set its `<li>` childs to `float: none` so that they are centered.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

/* Using display: inline-block to limit its width */

.tree > ul {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Clearing floats (so <ul> has a defined height) */

.tree ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
}

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tree .special {
  min-width: 94.594px;
}

.tree .special > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">2</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">2.1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">2.2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">3</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">3.1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">3.2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="special">
          <a href="#">4</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">4.1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. Could you please edit your example to turn the node text horizontal?

Comment: Simply use `transform: rotate` again on the desired elements. If you want to rotate the text only you'll have to wrap them in `<span>` elements

Comment: Ok, I will try it. But I mentioned that the graphic overlaps the top edge.

Comment: Use `transform-origin: bottom` or pixel values (x and y) to adjust it the way you want. You can also add a min-height on `<div class="tree">` equivalent to the height of your tree node so that it doesn't break your layout. And if you want to rotate the graphic and the text it means that the whole thing should have been horizontal and therefore not coded this way.